# Trigger HTML event with VBA

Tags: html, vba, dom, internet-explorer-8

i try to simulate the same events with code, that happen when i click the button. 
References i use are **Microsoft HTML Object Library** & **Microsoft Internet Controls**

The html event is "onclick", the following line is from the source code

```
main.cabPestanaV2_1.select('WeitereDaten');;return false;
```

When i try to access the object "WeitereDaten" through getElementByID, nothing happens, so i try to figure out the necessary events...

```
Document.getElementById("WeitereDaten").click
```

or

```
Document.getElementById("WeitereDaten").FireEvent ("onclick")
```

doesnt return an error, but the button isnt actually clicked (nothing happens).

[html source code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVgAd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Document.getElementById("WeitereDaten").click
> ```

This won't work because the element doesn't have an `Id` - so the `getElementById` method will return `Nothing`

You best bet is to use:

```
Dim myLinks As Object
Set myLinks = Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Then iterate over the `myLinks` object which is a `HTMLcollection` and test each element to see if it's the link you require. Once you've identified the correct element *then* you can attempt to fire one of it's events.

Unfortunately, as there is no unique identifier that can be parsed using the DOM object you have no way of accessing the element directly in VBA.

Comment: `If not Document.getElementById("WeitereDaten") Is nothing Then
'runs code
End if `

Kinda works, so i guess the return isnt nothing?

Comment: Except there is no element with an ID of "WeitereDaten" so it's never going to work. That's my point

Comment: I mean the element that you're trying to get at - which doesn't have an `id` attribute. If it did, your code would work

Comment: Aaah, okay sorry for not getting it... I'll try with byTagName